# Batch to find a string of number&letter combination only in first 10 characters (in a txt file) per row and print the whole row

Tags: string, batch-file, cmd, find

I have a question regarding batch file. I need a batch file which will find a string of number&letter combination in only first 10 letters per row (in a multiple .txt files) and print out the whole row into an output .txt file. At the moment i have been using this:

```
@echo off  
findstr "A1234 B5678" "*.txt"  
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('findstr "A1234 B5678" "*.txt"') do (echo %%A >> OUTPUTFILE.txt)
```

So what I am looking for in above is a combination of letters A1234 and B5678 (just an example) in all txt files in directory and printing them out into outputfile.txt. It works out just fine but i need to improve this a little. I only want batch to find this combination (A1234 and B5678) in only first 10 letters  per row and print the whole row into an output txt file. For Example we would have a multiple txt files which would have in themself lines like these:

```
00 A1234 QWERTZ  
AA B5678 ASDFGH
```

Batch would check all the files for string combination A1234 and B5678 and would print out the whole row which had that combination in them.
I hope you guys will understand me, because my english is not the best. Also I am not very much experienced in cmd so if possible, please make it as easy(understandable) as possible :).
Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another way to do it that is a bit more complicated, but it does not rely on extra code.
It slices all txt files in the current directory into lines. The first 10 characters of these lines are feed into findstr. If findstr succeeds it echos the line to the console.

Use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir/B *.txt') do (
    for /f "delims=" %%J in (%%I) do (
        set "_=%%J"
        call echo %%_:~0,10%%|findstr "PATTERN1 PATTERN2"&&call echo %%_%%
    )
)
endlocal
goto:eof
```

For the cracks: I know there is ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION. So the call style could be avoided by using

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
```

and

```
        echo !_:~0,10!|findstr "PATERN1 PATERN2"&&call echo !_!
```

But I deem this as bad style, because this tends to cause problems, especially if anything you want to echo includes '!' So I always use the call and double %% style in my examples, except the DELAYEDEXPANSION cannot be avoided.

Comment: This works great - when i run the batch file it seeks correctly! One more request - how can i make it so that it will print the results into txt file?

Comment: Oh nevermind, figured it out, added ">> output.txt" after the "echo %%_%%" part and it works great! Thanks for your help and everyone elses too! :)

Comment: Better to use the redirection from outside. If filter.bat is your batch file, you can start it with "filter>output.txt" and all output of the batch file will be redirected into output.txt.

Comment: If I do it like that it prints out the results twice - dont know why but it just does...

Comment: maybe you didn't remove the "internal >> output.txt" from the batch file?

Comment: No, I removed that one. Even when I run the batch file with your script only, I see the rows twice. But it doesnt matter as for me the main problem was to search first 10 letters in txt file and this point has been taken care of by your script :).

Answer (score 0):

If you are dead set on using cmd, you can use findstr with the regex flag as follows:

```
C:\>type test.txt
00 A1234 QWERTZ
AA B5678 ASDFGH
BB A1234 B5678
00 A1234 QWERTZ
AA B5678 ASDFGH
BB A1234 B5678
00 A1234 QWERTZ
AA B5678 ASDFGH
BB A1234 B5678
00 A1234 QWERTZ
AA B5678 ASDFGH
BB A1234 B5678
00 A1234 QWERTZ
AA B5678 ASDFGH
BB A1234 B5678
00 A1234 QWERTZ
AA B5678 ASDFGH
BB A1234 B5678
00 A1234 QWERTZ
AA B5678 ASDFGH
BB A1234 B5678

C:\>findstr /R "^*[A][0-9]* [B][0-9]*$" test.txt
BB A1234 B5678
BB A1234 B5678
BB A1234 B5678
BB A1234 B5678
BB A1234 B5678
BB A1234 B5678
BB A1234 B5678
```

-- ab1

Comment: Not exactly what I meant. I dont need the A1234 and B5678 to be on the same row together. I need a batch to find either one of them (A1234 OR B5678) in first 10 letters on row and print out the whole row.

Comment: Findstr doesn't support conditionals, you could use grep in one line ('grep -E "[A]{1}[1-4]{4}|[B]{1}[5-8]{4}" test.txt').

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you want to search in the first 10 characters for multiple specific alphanumeric combinations. I think you can do this with a regular expression, but 
unfortunately findstr cannot handle alternative patterns.

```
findstr /r "(pattern1|pattern2)"
```

does not work. So you have to branch out to grep for windows which can be found [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm)
The syntax for n patterns is:

```
grep -h -E -e "^.. ({PATTERN 1}|{PATTERN 2}|...|{PATTERN 2})" *.txt
```

So for your example you can use:

```
grep -h -E -e "^.. (A1234|B5678)" *.txt
```

search in every *.txt for any line that begins with 2 random letters followed by a space followed by A1234 or B5678 and prints out this line. The -h in the beginning supresses the output of the filename of the line.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I will check/test it out and let you know about the result.

Comment: So i dont have the administrator rights on my work PC so i cant install the grep. Is there however any alternative way of doing this?

Comment: Well you don't need admin rights to install grep, you can unzip the zip file with the binaries into your batch folder.

Comment: You could also take a look at my second answer, that needs no additional requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This uses a helper batch file called `findrepl.bat` which is similar to grep but runs as a plain batch file - it can be found here - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4697

findrepl.bat uses `jscript` in the Windows Scripting Host and it will work unless your IT admin have disabled WSH.

```
@echo off 
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
echo ============="%%a"================>>search
type "%%a"|findrepl "^.. (A1234|B5678)">>search 
)
ren search search.txt
```