# Findstr Batch - if string not found print "not found"

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, findstr

I'm trying to find multiple strings in the first few characters of the line of some text files. If a particular string searched for is not found, print "no xxxx found".
I'm trying to use a batch script, but am willing to use grep or other.

My code is based off of [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23818504/batch-find-a-string-in-first-10-characters-on-line-and-print-whole-line) and I've copied it below, thanks @Aacini.
This works great! And almost solves my problem. Output is as follows:

```
R0621 ***
32411 ***
R0621 ***
32411 *** 
R0621 *** 
R0621 ***  
32411 ***
```

What I'd like is:

```
R0621 ***
32411 ***
R0621 ***
32411 *** 
R0621 ***
no 32411 found 
R0621 ***  
32411 ***
```

Every file (should) have R0621, but not every file will have 32411.

To simplify I'll use the previous example which is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Seek the target strings in all .txt files
(for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr "R0621 32411" *.txt') do (
   rem Check that the target string(s) exists in first 10 characters of found lines
   set "line=%%b"
   rem Get just the first 10 characters
   set "tenChars=!line:~0,10!"
   rem If R0621 was in first 10 characters
   if "!tenChars:R0621=!" neq "!tenChars!" (
      echo !line!
   rem If 32411 was in first 10 characters
   ) else if "!tenChars:32411=!" neq "!tenChars!" (
      echo !line!
   )
)) > search.out
```

I've tried lots of things.

Nested ifs in multiple locations with and without pipes:

```
   if "!tenChars:R0621=!" neq "!tenChars!" (
      echo !line!
   rem If 32411 was in first 10 characters
   ) else if echo "not found" |"!tenChars:32411=!" neq "!tenChars!" (
      echo !line!
   )
```

Using error levels:

```
if "!tenChars:R0621=!" neq "!tenChars!" (
          echo !line!
       IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 Echo "An error was found"
       rem If 32411 was in first 10 characters
       ) else if "!tenChars:32411=!" neq "!tenChars!" (
          echo !line!
       )
```

My current thinking is running this .bat file and then parsing the "search.txt" output file looking for R0621 and 32411 on each line. But I'm sure there is an error level or nested if solution.

Edit:
Code as requested.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem the above code changes 
rem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23818504/batch-find-a-string-in-first-10-characters-on-line-and-print-whole-line
rem Seek the target strings in all .las files
(for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /S "VERS WRAP DLM STRT STOP STEP NULL COMP WELL FLD LOC SRVC CTRY DATE X Y GDAT HZCS LONG LAT" *.las') do (

   rem Check that the target string(s) exists in first 5 characters of found lines
   set "line=%%b"
rem    set %path=%%~nx1
   rem Get just the first 5 characters
   set "fiveChars=!line:~0,5!"
   rem Get just the first 2 characters
   set "twoChars=!line:~0,2!"
   rem If VARS was in first 5 characters
   if "!fiveChars:VERS=!" neq "!fiveChars!" (
      rem !! means do a command, %% means this is a command in this, a batch file, ~ means run this command, f=filepath, a=the variable name
      echo !%%~fa!
      echo !line!
   rem If WRAP was in first 5 characters
   ) else if "!fiveChars:WRAP=!" neq "!fiveChars!" (
      echo !line!
   rem If DLM was in first 5 characters
   ) else if "!fiveChars:DLM=!" neq "!fiveChars!" (
      echo !line!
   rem If STRT was in first 5 characters
   ) else if "!fiveChars:STRT=!" neq "!fiveChars!" (
      echo !line!
   rem If STOP was in first 5 characters
   ) else if "!fiveChars:STOP=!" neq "!fiveChars!" (
      echo !line!
   rem If STEP was in first 5 characters
   ) else if "!fiveChars:STEP=!" neq "!fiveChars!" (
      echo !line!
   rem If NULL was in first 5 characters
   ) else if "!fiveChars:NULL=!" neq "!fiveChars!" (
      echo !line!
   rem If COMP was in first 5 characters
   ) else if "!fiveChars:COMP=!" neq "!fiveChars!" (
      echo !line!
   rem If WELL was in first 5 characters
   ) else if "!fiveChars:WELL=!" neq "!fiveChars!" (
      echo !line!
   rem If FLD was in first 5 characters
   ) else if "!fiveChars:FLD=!" neq "!fiveChars!" (
      echo !line!
   rem If LOC was in first 5 characters
   ) else if "!fiveChars:LOC=!" neq "!fiveChars!" (
      echo !line!
   rem If SRVC was in first 5 characters
   ) else if "!fiveChars:SRVC=!" neq "!fiveChars!" (
      echo !line!
   rem If CTRY was in first 5 characters
   ) else if "!fiveChars:CTRY=!" neq "!fiveChars!" (
      echo !line!
   rem If DATE was in first 5 characters
   ) else if "!fiveChars:DATE=!" neq "!fiveChars!" (
      echo !line!
   rem If GDAT was in first 5 characters
   ) else if "!fiveChars:GDAT=!" neq "!fiveChars!" (
      echo !line!
   rem If HZCS was in first 5 characters
   ) else if "!fiveChars:HZCS=!" neq "!fiveChars!" (
      echo !line!
   rem If LONG was in first 5 characters
   ) else if "!fiveChars:LONG=!" neq "!fiveChars!" (
      echo !line!
   rem If LAT was in first 5 characters
   ) else if "!fiveChars:LAT=!" neq "!fiveChars!" (
      echo !line!
   rem If X was in first 2 characters
   ) else if "!twoChars:X=!" neq "!twoChars!" (
      echo !line!
   rem If Y was in first 2 characters
   ) else if "!twoChars:Y=!" neq "!twoChars!" (
      echo !line!
   )
)) > findstr.csv
pause
```

The output looks like this.

```
\Filepath.las
 VERS              .         2.0                           : CWLS LOG ASCII STANDARD - VERSION 2.0
 WRAP              .         NO                            : ONE LINE PER DEPTH STEP
 DLM               .         SPACE                         : DELIMITING CHARACTER(SPACE TAB OR COMMA)
STRT               .m        518.9                         : First reference value
STOP               .m        840.96                        : Last reference value
STEP               .m        0.02                          : Step increment
NULL               .         -9999                         : Missing value
COMP               .         M.I.M. HOLDINGS LIMITED       : Company
WELL               .         DR06                          : Well name
FLD                .         DAWSON RIVER                  : Field
LOC                .         ATP 524P                      : Location
SRVC               .         EMERALD                       : Service Company
DATE               .         29-Oct-94                     : Date
CTRY               .         AUSTRALIA                     : Country
X                  .m        804354.25                     : X
Y                  .m        7253497.98                    : Y
HZCS               .         MGA94 - ZONE 55               : Horizontal Coordinate System
LATI               .                                       : Latitude
LONG               .                                       : Longitude
\Filepath2.las
 VERS              .         2.0                           : CWLS LOG ASCII STANDARD - VERSION 2.0
 WRAP              .         NO                            : ONE LINE PER DEPTH STEP
 DLM               .         SPACE                         : DELIMITING CHARACTER(SPACE TAB OR COMMA)
STRT               .m        518.9                         : First reference value
STOP               .m        840.96                        : Last reference value
STEP               .m        0.02                          : Step increment
NULL               .         -9999                         : Missing value
COMP               .         M.I.M. HOLDINGS LIMITED       : Company
WELL               .         DR06                          : Well name
FLD                .         DAWSON RIVER                  : Field
LOC                .         ATP 524P                      : Location
SRVC               .         EMERALD                       : Service Company
DATE               .         29-Oct-94                     : Date
CTRY               .         AUSTRALIA                     : Country
X                  .m        804354.25                     : X
Y                  .m        7253497.98                    : Y
HZCS               .         MGA94 - ZONE 55               : Horizontal Coordinate System
LATI               .                                       : Latitude
LONG               .                                       : Longitude
\Filepath3.las
 VERS.                1.20:  CWLS log ASCII Standard -Version 1.20
 WRAP.                  NO:  One line per depth step
 STRT.M              518.9:
 STOP.M              841.2:
 STEP.M                .10:
 NULL.                   0:
 COMP.             COMPANY:  MIM HOLDINGS LTD              
 WELL.                WELL:  DR6 - NEUTRON LOG             
 FLD.                FIELD:  ATP 524P                      
 LOC .            LOCATION:                   
 SRVC.     SERVICE COMPANY:  EMERALD     
 DATE.            LOG DATE:  10/29/94
 LAT .            LATITUDE:  7253317N
```

Comment: The entire methodology you're using doesn't make sense to me. `findstr "R0621 32411" *.txt` will only return every line in each .txt file containing either of the character sequences, `R0621` or `32411`. So it doesn't matter how many characters you're checking on each result, because if the line doesn't contain `32411`, then it will never contain it in those characters. Instead of trying to give us code and examples for someone else's problem, please submit your examples instead. Post your own example text files, your own search strings and your own code, so that we can assist with your issue.

Comment: Using a similar method to the other answer in your linked post, the following single line will list all text files which contain either of those two example strings within the first ten characters of any line, `@%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /IM "^R0621 ^.R0621 ^..R0621 ^...R0621 ^....R0621 ^.....R0621 ^32411 ^.32411 ^..32411 ^...32411 ^....32411 ^.....32411" "*.txt" 2>NUL`. If nothing else, this will mean that the result set you're wanting to parse the individual lines of would contain at least one case insensitive match of at least one of your search strings, somewhere within it.

Comment: @Compo, definitely understand what you're saying regarding if '32411' is not found should it print every non- '32411' line.

Comment: @Compo Added my code as requested. I'll try my solution on the output file.

Comment: Okay, I assume means `findstr.csv`. However this means more questions and observations. To start with, from my limited knowledge of las files, I would have expected other matches, most noticeably the section names which are prepended with `~`, and should include, `~Version`, and `~Well`, matching `VERS` and `WELL`. I also doubt that `X` and `Y` are wise additions for anywhere in the first five characters, because you can already see from your others search strings that `Y` will already match `CTRY`, and I doubt that there wouldn't be other similar collisions within those or the other sections.

Comment: The actual task need to be explained, because it almost apprears that you're simply pulling out the Version and Well sections of all of your las files. Possibly removing those section name lines and one or other less standard header items. What I do not understand is how what you've now included has anything to do with printing lines which were 'not found'. My first instinct however, is that it is most likely that batch files are the wrong tool for the job, but rather a tool or scripting language which was designed to parse files, preferably with regex.

Comment: First off, thanks for your answer @Compo. The task is: here is a folder full of Las files, create a database to find errors and duplicates. For each file I'm expecting a VERS line, a WRAP line, a DLM line etc, all to a LAS standard. I'm looking for LAS files that are missing data have omitted one of those standard lines.

Comment: I've settled for using the "incomplete" findstr.csv. I run the output in Google Sheets with a Filter that grabs the range of each file, then an index match on each key word in that range. Each time no key word is found in that range an error results. I believe that for my above code an Error level check is the solution, but I can't get it to work.